# Why does Scala fires the trim function in None.map(_.trim)?

Tags: scala

I have a line of code like this:

```
Option(str).map(_.trim).getOrElse("")
```

The idea is simple: trim the input string or return a blank string if there is none.

But it fails in the scala console when str is `null`: error: value trim is not a member of Null

The reason is obvious since scala triggers the function in `map()` even when the object is `None`. But isn't it supposed to return `None` directly?

Comment: See @Larsenal's answer below. The problem isn't that `trim` actually gets called, but that the compiler fails during type checking since the `Null` class has no `trim` method.

Comment: @NSF errors like *error: value trim is not a member of Null* happen at **compile** time so there is no triggering at all (yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 2.9.1, it works for me:

```
scala> val x : Option[String] = Option(null)
x: Option[String] = None

scala> x.map{_.length}
res4: Option[Int] = None
```

Does not work because the type is `Option[Null]` instead of `Option[String]`:

```
scala> Option(null).map(_.trim)
<console>:8: error: value trim is not a member of Null
              Option(null).map(_.trim)
```

Does work if you give it the correct type:

```
scala> Option[String](null).map(_.trim)
res3: Option[java.lang.String] = None
```

Comment: Nice catch! If he doesn't give an explicit type then Scala will infer type `Null` for `null`. This should work too: `Option(null:String).map(_.trim)`

Comment: Interesting! It seems like although Option(null:Null) returns None but it's still like Some(null)?

Comment: You're not seeing a runtime error.  It knows from the types that you can't call `trim` on a null.  So it's really just failing the type checking.

Comment: @Larsenal Ah. That makes perfect sense. Thanks.